# Why can't I use attributes from android.R.attr?

Tags: android

I cannot directly use "?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft" in my XML (I get a android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException).

I can only make it work using this code:

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft, value, true);
```

to get the dimension then go through some hoops using getDimension() and DisplayMetrics before manually setting it.

Is there a way to avoid this?